# Install Teradatasql on Microsoft R Open (MRO) 3.5.3

Tags: r, teradata, microsoft-r, teradatasql

Official [Teradata Download Site](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-sql-driver-for-r) and it's [Github counterpart](https://github.com/Teradata/r-driver#teradata-sql-driver-for-r) say Teradata's R driver requires R 3.4.3+. BUT, trying to install on Microsoft R Open 3.5.3 raise the below

- teradatasql_16.20.0.38.tar.gz

> Error : package ‘digest’ 0.6.18 was found, but >= 0.6.22 is required
> by ‘teradatasql’

- teradatasql_17.0.0.7.tar.gz

> Error : package ‘bit64’ 0.9.7 was found, but >= 4.0.5 is required by ‘teradatasql’

Above 2 versions are the only ones mentioned in [their site](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-sql-driver-for-r), which can also be downloaded upon registration. Does anybody know what teradata driver's version is matching [Microsoft R Open 3.5.3](https://mran.microsoft.com/release-history) ? Or, any alternative method to get a teradatasql driver working on MRO 3.5.3?

Comment: Microsoft R Open defaults to using a snapshot of CRAN as of a point in time (15 Apr 2019 in the case of 3.5.3), with the intent of providing consistent behavior for everyone on the same MRO release. Use Microsoft's `checkpoint` package prior to the install, to select a more recent CRAN snapshot.

Comment: Thanks. Then, what was the teradatasql version at April 2019? (if possible, I'd feel safer staying on the consistent side and keep using such snapshot)

Comment: I suppose the change history on GitHub would let you figure out an old version number for that timeframe. But I don't know where you could obtain the old software. The other option would be to use the current MRO.